# Imprimir en consola db.execSQL en Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

¿Como puedo sacar por consola esta cadena? Quiero sacar por consola y ver si genero bien la sentencia. No se que parametro usar para cargarlo en el System.out.print

```
db.execSQL(String.format("CREATE TABLE %s (%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                    "%s TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,%s TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,%s INTEGER NOT NULL)",
            Tablas.VALOR, MetadatosDB.Valores.ID_VALOR,
            MetadatosDB.Valores.NOMBRE, MetadatosDB.Valores.CODIGO,
            MetadatosDB.Valores.SITUACION));

System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mete el valor del String.format en una variable. Asi:

```
String consulta = String.format("CREATE TABLE %s (%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                "%s TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,%s TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,%s INTEGER NOT NULL)",
        Tablas.VALOR, MetadatosDB.Valores.ID_VALOR,
        MetadatosDB.Valores.NOMBRE, MetadatosDB.Valores.CODIGO,
        MetadatosDB.Valores.SITUACION);

db.execSQL(consulta);
System.out.println(consulta);
```